# Is there a way to unfreeze filesystem after it is freezed and program terminates abruptly?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount-point, ext3, xfs

After doing an **xfs_freeze -f /mntpoint**

if the program terminates abruptly, the filesystem will remain in freeze(suspended) state.

Is there any way other than manually executing the unfreeze command : **xfs_freeze -u /mntpoint** to handle it in a better way?